# Vertical alignment of column rows in Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Suppose you have a two-column layout using Twitter Bootstrap, in which you want to have specific rows vertically aligned with each other:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Optional content of variable height.</p>
      <p><strong>Align this vertically...</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p><strong>...with this</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vertical alignment is feasible with table layouts, however, sizing and responsive behaviour of Bootstrap's columns is lost:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="row">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><h2>Column 1</h2></th>
        <th scope="col"><h2>Column 2</h2></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Optional content of variable height.</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Align this vertically...</strong></td>
        <td><strong>...with this</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Another option is to split rows, however, the layout folds in wrong order on smaller resolutions.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Optional content of variable height.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <strong>Align this vertically...</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <strong>...with this</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do you achieve the same result while still maintaining the behaviour of Bootstrap's columns? Is using table layout the way to go or is it a dead-end? Is it otherwise possible without resorting to JavaScript to position a row to a computed offset?

EDIT: I aim to have the top of the rows aligned as is the case in the table layout.

Comment: `Align this vertically...` will be of variable height or fixed height?

Comment: Did you define the height? Maybe you can show us your css.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: The content to align has variable height.

Comment: @HermLuna: No, I didn't. I only use the default Twitter Bootstrap CSS, which is included in the snippets.

Comment: @jindrichm well, I assume you use bootstrap 3. I don't think it has the capability of aligning elements vertically. Bootstrap 4 will have the vertical aligning because of integration of flexbox. Bootstrap 3 is more on float. Unfortunately, bootstrap 4 is still on alpha or beta.

Comment: @HermLuna: As you can see in the snippets, I use Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha. Can you explain how to achieve the vertical alignment in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/ read this one.

Comment: Can you outline how a solution for the vertical alignment would work in flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, I would test these solutions.

**Solution 1** : Using Javascript (Jquery if you want) to detect the height of the left and the right div, and to tell them to have the same height.

You can apply this solution on the second content div to make the espace above your bold text having the same height.

Or to add.. for example as margin-top as needed in the smaller div (with bold text which need to be aligned) after comparing the heights of both.

Anyway, if you have both of theirs heights you will have enought informations to find a way. Multiples solutions are possible here, I let you find the better one for your context and needs.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 leftcolumn">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <div class="astallas"><p>Optional content of variable height.</p></div>
      <p><strong>Align this vertically...</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 rightcolumn">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <div class="astallas"></div> // make this empty div have the same height that the left one with variable content
      <p><strong>...with this</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2** (but with some browsers incompatibilties) : Use Flexbox <3 which is a native CSS3 fonctionnaly that give you a easy way to have your wanted divs' positions. 
http://flexboxfroggy.com/ 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I think that both of these works with bootstrap and will respect responsive needs.

Comment: I don't want to center the rows vertically in their container. Instead, I want to  align their tops. Can you outline how the flexbox solution could work?

Comment: I was rethinking a little my reply. It will certainly respond to your comment now.
About flexbox, you will quickly understand visiting some of the given links. It's very powerfull then it's quite sure that will find a way to make your move using it

Comment: I worked my way through the resources you linked (Flexbox Froggy is great!), but it's still unclear which flexbox property can help me solve my problem. Can you point me to the properties that you think could help?

Comment: Yes these exercices are so cool and offer a nice way to learn it. 
I will have a look, I do not use it often then I check website which give example in general. I come back ;)

Comment: A simple idea : If I remember you are able to make 2 columns with same height and then telling your 3 div in it to be on the top, on the middle, and the bottom. 
I think would be as simple as that.. ? 

I'll check the attributes needed.

http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/jqzNZq 
This example give you the fact that Aside1 and 2 (your two columns) can share a row > same height. And then you align-self: end your bold text content.

Comment: That won't work: the rows in columns would be aligned to their center, while I want their tops to be aligned.

Comment: Also note that there may be other content after the aligned rows, so that `align-self: end;` won't work.

Comment: I think that everything is possible if you separate your elements enought in the way to make the structure needed. 
That will be as a table but with more flexibility

Comment: What do you mean by separating elements enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get rows of equal heights:

```
<style>
 .centered {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0;
  }

 .centered .myheight{
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 13px;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-bottom: 5px; /*add this if you want to give some gap between the rows. */
  }
</style>


<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-sm-4 myheight">
      Some  content
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 myheight">
      Some  content ...<br>
      Some more content
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 myheight">
      Some  content
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4 myheight">
      Some  content
    </div>                                                              
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this produces rows with equal heights, see https://jsfiddle.net/59r6gLk0/5/.